# Merge rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

| ID | Time | Name | Size | Sold | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0500 | Unit | 12 | Nan | Nan |
| 1 | 0500 | Nan | Nan | 1 | Nan |
| 1 | 0500 | Nan | Nan | Nan | 2 |
| 2 | 0500 | Unit2 | 10 | Nan | Nan |
| 2 | 0500 | Nan | Nan | Nan | 3 |
| 2 | 0500 | Nan | Nan | 1 | Nan |

It is much longer than this, but it is from three data frames that were concatenated (that I can't control, I only have access to this dataframe). How can I combine the rows based on common values like ID and Time to get this result:

| ID | Time | Name | Size | Sold | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0500 | Unit | 12 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0500 | Unit2 | 10 | 1 | 3 |

This seems like it should be easy but I am stumped. I tried `df.groupby(['ID', 'Time'])` but it just gave me the name/type of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `fill`, `bfill` to fill the nulls and then `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()


   ID  Time  Name Size Sold Stock
0   1   500  Unit   12    1     2
```

Note that this won't work if the `NaN` are not actual missing values.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! When I try that, I get an error: unhashable type: 'list', although I am positive it is a data frame so I am not sure why?

Comment: kindly share ``df.dtypes``

Comment: ID: object, Time: float64, Name: object, Size: float64, Sold: float64, Stock: float64

Comment: Hmmmm... And you ran the code on the data you shared?